# VB.NET: Saving text directly as encrypted file, without conversion

Tags: vb.net, file, encryption

I'm looking for a way to save text directly to an encrypted file, without saving it to a plain text file and encrypt this text file afterwards.

I don't care about the encryption type used as long as it is easy to implement and secure enough..

Preferably in VB.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the encryption algorithm of your choice from the System.Security.Cryptography namespace and encrypt the string before writing it into the text file.

Comment: So there are no difference between a encrypted file and a plain file with encrypted content?